# eBay timestamp and timezone

Tags: php, timestamp, timezone

I have tried to crack at this for days now, and it has come to the point where its driving my head in.

I am trying to make a function, that will format ebay time (Dec 27, 2013 05:26:29 PST) into a Unix timestamp but somehow my system changes the timestamp with a very wrong timezone.

Here is the code to get the date from ebay.

```
function getEndDate($itemno, $html) 
{
    global $settings;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    //<span class="vi-tm-left" id="vi-cdown_timeLeft">
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $elements = $xpath->query('//span[@class="vi-tm-left"]');
    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $enddate = strip_tags($element->nodeValue);
            $enddate = str_replace("(","", $enddate);
            $enddate = str_replace(")","", $enddate);
            $enddate = convertEbayStamp($enddate);
            return $enddate;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here is my awesome convert it to `timestamp` function:

```
function convertEbayStamp($stamp) {
    $months = array('Jan' => 1, 'Feb' => 2, 'Mar' => 3, 'Apr' => 4, 'May' => 5, 'Jun' => 6, 'Jul' => 7, 'Aug' => 8, 'Sep' => 9, 'Oct' => 10, 'Nov' => 11, 'Dec' => 12);
    $arr = explode(" ",$stamp);
        // arr[0] = Dec, arr[1] = 31, // arr[2] = 2013, // arr[3] = 21:15:01 // arr[4] = PST
    $month = $months[$arr[0]];
    $day = str_replace(",","",$arr[1]);
    $timeelements = explode(":",$arr[3]);

    return mktime($timeelements[0],$timeelements[1],$timeelements[2], $month, $day, $arr[2]);       
}
```

Sadly none of what I have done, setting the `date_timezone_set` has worked for me, neither have using DateTime.

Comment: mktime's last parameter is the daylight savings param, which defaults to -1, which can result in unexpected results. Have you tried explicitly setting it?

Comment: Did you tried to use `strtotime` or `strptime` functions?

Comment: @Zarazthuztra - I haven't tried to set it. But i dont think daylight saving param is going to do me any good when i need the time in PST instead of UTC :)

Comment: @Orifjon I have tried many different combinations, however it either returned 0 or it simply turned the timestamp -18988 years etc back in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it all wrong. The best way to get a timestamp from a non-standard date format is to use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). No need for all those crazy `explode()`s all over the place and trying to hard-code the month name in. Just tell PHP what format you're expecting and it will try to get a DateTime object out of it.

(Note that the timezone provided by eBay (`PST`) is not a valid timezone in PHP, so it won't be automatically regonized by `DateTime::createFromFormat`. I have hard-coded it in below. If the timezone changes, you could change the `$tz` variable to match the [desired timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php) and change `\P\S\T` to match whatever is provided by eBay.)

```
<?php

$string = '(Dec 27, 2013 05:26:29 PST)';
$tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'; // Choose a city in your desired time zone. See link above.

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('(M j, Y H:i:s \P\S\T)', $string, new DateTimeZone($tz));
echo $dt->getTimestamp(); // echoes 1388150789
```

Also, it's worth noting that Unix time stamps **do not** have have time zones. It is defined as<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)</sup> the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

**Edit for php 5.2**:

Even though I strongly recommend you your PHP since 5.2 is [no longer supported](http://php.net/eol.php) and hasn't been for over 2 years now, here is a workaround I think should be compatible with 5.2, since the date is *almost* recognized by PHP natively. You just need to get rid of the brackets and time zone. It's a bit uglier, but it works:

```
$string = '(Dec 27, 2013 05:26:29 PST)';
$tz = 'America/Los_Angeles';

preg_match('/^\((.*) PST\)$/', $string, $matches);
$string = $matches[1];

$dt = new DateTime($string, new DateTimeZone($tz));
echo $dt->format('U'); // echoes 1388150789
```

This appears to [work for PHP 5.2](http://3v4l.org/K0EdS).

Comment: That is my problem. Since i am using php 5.2 i cannot use createFormFormat. I need a workaround so that i can get it working on php 5.2. And thanks Mike for taking the time to answer my post.

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.2 you *really* need to upgrade it. There is no reason to be using such an outdated version. If you're using shared hosting and your host is still using 5.2, run! It has been at its [end of life](http://php.net/eol.php) for more than 2 years now.

Comment: all i can do is try to work around it. Some of the other programs i work with also does'nt support 5.3 yet. Its being worked on by the authors.

Comment: @ToneIreneAndersen I just realized `DateTime::getTimestamp()` is also not available, so I changed it again.

Comment: I've tried these examples now.. both for php 5.2 and php 5.4 but in 5.4 it just doesn't work with DateTime, it just basicly return =now timestamp and thats wrong.

Comment: (Dec 28, 2013 18:16:36 PST) returns 1388134904

Comment: I don't know how it's possible that it could return the wrong timestamp. It works fine for me. You probably did something else wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You only have this problem because you are applying screen scraping techniques to public HTML pages.  That is *not* how you should be interacting with eBay data.

eBay (like most popular web sites) has a [developer API](https://go.developer.ebay.com/).  If you used that, you would find that your date/time values are in standard [ISO-8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

See [eBay's API spec on `dateTime` types](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/shopping/docs/CallRef/types/simpleTypes.html#dateTime) for details.

Comment: I am not able to use the developer api because i am creating a multi user interface.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, scraping is prohibited by [eBay terms of service](http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/user-agreement.html#3).  Use the API.  You'll have a much more stable experience anyway.  Do you really want a future design change to eBay's pages to break your app?

Comment: The API is only active for one account. Do you expect to run an multi user interface on just one api? Hmm, maybe it is possible to get the item info i need by using the only one api for all the users.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how your users match up to eBay accounts. You may just be able to have one eBay account for your app.  Or potentially if each of your users has to access their own private eBay account, then you could use a different set of credentials per user.  You might want to ask about this separately. My only point is that the API is the prefered and legitimate way to go.

Comment: I signed up for the API.. I can at least make some tests so see if i can use it. :) Thanks

Comment: Ok heres is my problem again. The API is huge and it doesn't even have prebuildt classes, this will add several months to my work before im even close to a launch. Not to mention, coding for this is out of my league.

Comment: Here is a good place to start: [How to Integrate eBay APIs with Basic PHP, Part 1](https://go.developer.ebay.com/devzone/articles/how-to-integrate-ebay-apis-with-basic-php-part-1) and [Part 2](https://go.developer.ebay.com/devzone/articles/how-integrate-ebay-apis-basic-php-part-2).  If you need additional help, I urge you to consider authoring a new question specifically about whatever issues you run into.  This comment thread has gotten too far from the original topic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems legit and works on an online php executer, i just googled and tried. You should use DateTime formatting and take a good look at your server's time settings. Alternatively you can just calculate the difference between your result on your server and the online php compiler's and use it to add/substract on your functions result(hardcoded) but that's a bad practice.

Comment: It works. Its probably not how other coders would have done it, but i haven't been playing around with PHP for quite some time :)